# nodejs fs.exists()

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to call `fs.exists` in a node script but I get the error:

> TypeError: Object # has no method 'exists'

I've tried replacing `fs.exists()` with `require('fs').exists` and even `require('path').exists` (just in case), but neither of these even list the method `exists()` with my IDE. `fs` is declared at the top of my script as `fs = require('fs');` and I've used it previously to read files.

How can I call `exists()`?

Comment: What do you get if you do `console.log(Object.keys(fs));`? I doubt an IDE would list `exists` properly so don't worry about that.

Comment: What version of Node are you running? `exists` was moved from [`path`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.21/api/path.html#path_path_exists_p_callback) to `fs` for [0.8.x](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/API-changes-between-v0.6-and-v0.8).

Comment: hey guys cheers for the help, turns out for some reason my node had reverted to an older version so i got nvm up and running and installed the latest version, all works now.

Comment: From the documentation:

`fs.exists()` is an anachronism and exists only for historical reasons. There should almost never be a reason to use it in your own code.

In particular, checking if a file exists before opening it is an anti-pattern that leaves you vulnerable to race conditions: another process may remove the file between the calls to `fs.exists()` and `fs.open()`. Just open the file and handle the error when it's not there.

Comment: Could you post the relevant code sections? You could be missing a requires or using a different version. I once found a bug similar to

var myLib = './myLib.js';

So seeing the relevant code can be helpful.

Comment: While `fs.exists` is deprecated, `fs.existsSync` [is *not*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59792927), and will sometimes be easier to use than the alternatives

Answer (score 27):

Your require statement may be incorrect, make sure you have the following

```
var fs = require("fs");

fs.exists("/path/to/file",function(exists){
  // handle result
});
```

Read the documentation here

http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback

Comment: This is deprecated. Use [fs.stat](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback) or [fs.access](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_access_path_mode_callback) instead. (Note: Reason for the comment is this comes up first in Google search for fs.exists)

Answer (score 22):

You should be using `fs.stats` or `fs.access` instead. From the [node documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback), exists is deprecated (possibly removed.)

If you are trying to do more than check existence, the documentation says to use `fs.open`.  For example:

```js
fs.access('myfile', (err) => {
  if (!err) {
    console.log('myfile exists and I have access');
    return;
  }
  console.log('myfile does not exist or I do not have access');
});
```

And now with async promises being the norm you actually can wrap this:

```js
import { access } from 'node:fs/promises';

try {
  await access('myfile');
  console.log('myfile exists and I have access');
} catch (error) {
  console.log('myfile does not exist or I do not have access');
}
```

(What's does `node:` mean in the import statement, the `node` prevents someone from hijacking your fs package and injecting malicious code into your application. Always use `node:` prefix when your runtime supports it).

Comment: Be careful since `fs.access` can also return error in case when file exists, but you have no write permissions.
Check [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_access_path_mode_callback) for more details.

Answer (score 7):

As others have pointed out, `fs.exists` is deprecated, in part because it uses a single `(success: boolean)` parameter instead of the *much* more common `(error, result)` parameters present nearly everywhere else.

However, `fs.existsSync` is *not* deprecated (because it doesn't use a callback, it just returns a value), and if the whole rest of your script depends on checking the existence of a single file, it can make things easier than having to deal with callbacks or surrounding the call with `try`/`catch` (in the case of `accessSync`):

```
const fs = require('fs');
if (fs.existsSync(path)) {
  // It exists
} else {
  // It doesn't exist
}
```

Of course, `existsSync` is synchronous and *blocking*. While this can sometimes be handy, if you need to do other operations in parallel (such as checking for the existence of multiple files at once), you should use one one of the other callback-based methods.

Modern versions of Node also support promise-based versions of `fs` methods, which one might prefer over callbacks:

```
fs.promises.access(path)
  .then(() => {
    // It exists
  })
  .catch(() => {
    // It doesn't exist
  });
```

Comment: That kind of defeats the purpose of using access, since its different to all other commands, you wouldn't expect to try catch your builtin deps ...

Answer (score 6):

Do NOT use fs.exists    [please read its API doc for alternative](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback)

this is the suggested alternative : go ahead and open file then handle error if any :

```
var fs = require('fs');

var cb_done_open_file = function(interesting_file, fd) {

    console.log("Done opening file : " + interesting_file);

    // we know the file exists and is readable
    // now do something interesting with given file handle
};

// ------------ open file -------------------- //

// var interesting_file = "/tmp/aaa"; // does not exist
var interesting_file = "/some/cool_file";

var open_flags = "r";

fs.open(interesting_file, open_flags, function(error, fd) {

    if (error) {

        // either file does not exist or simply is not readable
        throw new Error("ERROR - failed to open file : " + interesting_file);
    }

    cb_done_open_file(interesting_file, fd);
});
```

Comment: would be nice to also mention, that you should just put try()catch() block around your code that is reading the file. Beginners might be left wondering how else are they supposed to solve this problem.

Comment: fs.open is overkill, fs.access looks promising.