# Webpack check file exist and import in condition

Tags: reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

I use webpack in my react project.

I want check file in 'foo/myfile' and if that file exist import in my component, or load from 'bar/myfile'. 
for example:

```
let myModule;
if(webpackCheckFileExist('foo/myfile.jsx')){
  myModule = require('foo/myfile.jsx');
} else {
  myModule = require('bar/myfile.jsx');
}
```

I try:

```
if(__webpack_modules__[require.resolveWeak("foo/myfile.jsx")]) {
  // do something when mod1 is available
}
```

but if file dosnt exist - i catch webpack error

Comment: I write small webpack loader for this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/theme-customize-loader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: Use that method if you doesn`t want create one more chunk. For example: for use different `preview` files in you package in different projects and want have fallback without include to main package`s chunk.
For other cases create additional chunk is better way.

Checking file for exist - not best idea.
Config file such better because:

1. manipulate structure without remove files;
2. easy detect changes;

For include to bundle only useful files I write [theme-customize-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/theme-customize-loader). It`s webpack loader.

1. Add package
   `$ npm install theme-customize-loader --save-dev`
2. Add config file in your app

   ```
   const data = {
     MyModule: {
       Single : 'App/components/single/Single.jsx',
       Preview: 'my-theme/Preview',
     },
     OtherModule: {
       Preview: false,
     },
   };

   module.exports = data;
   ```

   Value can be path to file or false for fallback file.
3. Add to webpack configuration to rules section

   ```
   {
     enforce: 'pre',
     test   : /\.jsx$/,
     exclude: /node_modules/,
     use    : [{ loader: 'theme-customize-loader', options: { config: customizeConfig } }],
   },
   ```

   don`t forget import config file:
   `const customizeConfig = require('./App/configs/customize');`
4. Use in file. **Important:** In one string

   ```
   let loadComponent;
   /* customize path: "MyModule.Preview" var: "loadComponent" name: "my-chunk-name" origin: "../components/OriginPreview.jsx" */
   ```

More info you can find here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/theme-customize-loader

Answer (score 5):

You can use [require.context](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/context#requirecontext) and a regular expression to match files in the current folder, see the code below.

```
const requireCustomFile = require.context(
    './', false, /custom.js$/
)

requireCustomFile.keys().forEach(fileName => {
    requireCustomFile(fileName);
})
```

Answer (score 3):

This should help you. It just uses `fs` package of node.

```
var fs = require('fs');

if (fs.existsSync(path)) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. 
I don't use node from backend. I need build bundle.js for production. 
I want check file before use code

Comment: @nDiviD You don't necessarily have to use node at the back end. But your webpack runs on node, I hope you know that. You may have used `path` package in your webpack. I think `fs` can also be used! Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, you are right, webpack runs on node, but webpack ignored that part of code and  just puts in bundle.js. Code try detect file after complete compile. 
I want use in bundle.js only one of two files.

Comment: At least care to mention why you downvoted my answer.

Comment: `fs.exists` is [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59792927/104380) (long time before this answer was written apparently)

Answer (score 0):

A potential solution to your problem is to take advantage of the way that module resolution works.... No custom loader required!

If you leave off the extension and there is a file with the matching name then the file will be used, if the file is missing then it will check for a folder with the matching name and look for an `index.js` file in the folder. I have only tested this for typescript projects, and using `import` but it should work the same.
(see: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-resolution/#module-paths)

You could have something like this:

**some-file.js:**

```js
const myModule = require('./foo/myfile');
// ...
```

**foo/myfile/index.ts:** (note the `..` below is necessary)

```
module.exports = require('../bar/myfile.jsx')
```

Now, if `foo/myfile.jsx` doesn't exist then it would use the `foo/myfile/index.js` file which re-exports from the `bar/myfile.jsx`.

But, if `foo/myfile.jsx` exists then it would use that file. Problem solved!